# Angular 2 asynchronous validator with observable: TypeError: Cannot read property 'debounceTime' of undefined

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I am trying to get asynchronous validators to work with the Angular 2 Form builder but I keep getting this error in Chrome Console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'debounceTime' of undefined
```

I'm a bit lost. The control gets passed in but valueChanges seems to be undefined. I don't understand why.

My Custom Validator looks like this:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ReflectiveInjector} from 'angular2/core'
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

interface IUsernameValidator {
}

function checkUser(control: Control) : Observable<IUsernameValidator> {

  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
  let http = injector.get(Http);

  return new Observable((obs: any) => {
    control
      .valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .flatMap(value => http.post("http://localhost:4000/users/validate_username", JSON.stringify({ username: value })))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          obs.next(null);
          obs.complete();
        },
        error => {
          let message = error.json().message;
          let reason: string;
          if (message === 'Username taken') {
            reason = 'usernameTaken';
          }
          obs.next({ [reason]: true });
          obs.complete();
        }
    );
  });
}

export class UsernameValidator {

  constructor() {}

  static checkUsername(control: Control) {
    return checkUser(control);
  }
}
```

And my component that uses this Validator like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from 'angular2/common';
import { RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';

import { AdminService } from '../../shared/index';
import { UsernameValidator } from '../../shared/validators/username.validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'fac-admin-editor',
  templateUrl: 'app/+admins/editor/admin-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/+admins/editor/admin-editor.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [AdminService]
})
export class AdminEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  adminForm: ControlGroup;
  action: string;

  constructor(private adminService: AdminService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private params: RouteParams) {
    if(params.get('id') !== null) {
      this.adminService.getOne(params.get('id'));
      this.action = "edit";
    } else {
      this.action = "new";
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    var email_regex = '[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+@[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-z0-9\\.\\-\\_]+';
    if(this.action === "edit") {
      this.adminForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'username': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.minLength(5)
        ]), UsernameValidator.checkUsername],
        'password': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8)])],
        'password_confirmation': ['', Validators.required]
        }, {validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'password_confirmation')}
      );
    } else if (this.action === "new") {
      this.adminForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'username': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.minLength(5)
        ]), UsernameValidator.checkUsername],
        'password': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8)])],
        'password_confirmation': ['', Validators.required]
        }, {validator: matchingPasswords('password', 'password_confirmation')}
      );
    }
  }

}

function matchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, passwordConfirmationKey: string) {
  return (group: ControlGroup) => {
    let passwordInput = group.controls[passwordKey];
    let passwordConfirmationInput = group.controls[passwordConfirmationKey];
    if (passwordInput.value !== passwordConfirmationInput.value) {
      return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors({notequivalent: true})
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using 2.0.0-beta.17

Comment: Async validators still have a few issues https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8118. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9120, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9119, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7538 This is currently work in progress.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer None of these describe the issue I'm experiencing.

Comment: You are using sync and async validators together which is known to not work. There was a new forms module shippled in RC2 (not ready for use though) but I think it's not worth wasting too much time with the old deprecated module

Comment: I thought the idea was `[VALUE, SYNC_VALIDATORS, ASYNC_VALIDATORS]` (in pseudo-code). I just upgraded to rc2 and start looking at the new form module. But well, then I have to validate uniqueness of usernames on form submit server-side and wait until angular forms are more mature...